# How to run ios app continuously in background with user's permission

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, multitasking

I'm developing one iOS application which is related with OBD2. The app provides feature like connecting with obd2 device and read out data.

With user's permission, I want to implement below feature even if app is not running at all :

Now I want to do When user enters car, connection to obd2 device is to be done automatically and check for some params if i gets failure on those data then i need to send data to cloud for analysis.

How can i know about user enter car ? I'm thinking one way like continuously checking the Wifi Availability to OBD2 device and if i get wifi available then i can say "user is nearer to car or in the car".

But again problem is that if app is not running in the background then how can trigger this kind of event.My app is not supporting any background mode like voip, audio, location, newstand etc..

Is there any other way like local notification or any other way by which i can trigger event that user has entered in car even if app is not running at all ?

Can Background mode like Receive updates from External Accessory mode or External Accessory framework support me in this feature implementation ?

Can i develop this feature in such way that Apple approves this feature ?

Any other feedback or suggestion will be appreciated !

Comment: I realise that your hardware may already exist, but if it doesn't then Bluetooth Low Energy is a much better interface than WiFi for this application. CoreBluetooth supports automatic connection in the background and background data transfer

Comment: @Paulw11: Thanks. I will loook at CoreBluetooth in detail how it's going to support auto connection in background. I also want even if user has not used the app for 3-4 days but next day when he enters in car then auto connection should be done..

Comment: Yes, this will work. You can read about the background operation in the core bluetooth programming guide

Comment: Using Core Bluetooth, i can run app continuously in background mode by using CBCentral and CBPeripheral class. But i'ld like to know that i also need to send command and receive response when app is in foreground mode..How do i  take care of this by using socket communication or any other way. Actually Core bluetooth  talks about Service and Characteristics but i don't get how i can send command to obd dongle and receive response?

Comment: You don't use sockets. A peripheral defines one or more services. A service defines characteristics. Characteristics are like variables. They can be read or written. In your case your peripheral could define characteristics for things like Rpm, throttle position, coolant temperature etc.  You can either read these periodically or your peripheral can "notify" your app (Central) when a value changes

Comment: I came to know that by using Wifi Configuration profile, I may know that Once OBD2 Wifi dongle is connected in iOS Settings, iOS handle that notification and it may push app enables in background.

So if this thing is possible, I can do connection, perform health check and upload data to cloud by using OBD2 WiFi dongle.

Do you have any idea on this ?

Comment: The problem with wifi is that if the iOS device is connected to it then it will lose Internet access via 3G - you can implement wifi direct to get around this. Also there is no way of easily and reliably receiving information over wifi when the app is in the background or the screen is locked.

Comment: @Paulw11: In general case, if ios device is connected with Wifi then it will lose internet access via 3G. But we have done static Wifi so it's possible to run WiFi (with obd2 dongle) and internet (via 3G) simultaneously.